# How can I pass a CustomButton component to createAnimatedComponent?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm trying to make a `CustomButton` animate! I use `createAnimatedComponent` and `ref`. The button shows up but the animation does not work! I tried to comment out the colors in the `CustomButton` just in case the animated colors from the `createAnimatedComponent` didn't show up because of them, but nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

**CustomCreateAnimatedComp.js**

```
const AnimatedButton = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(CustomButton);

export default class CustomCreateAnimatedComp extends Component {
  state = {
    animation: new Animated.Value(0)
  };
  // for the ref button
  // Here our customButton gets detected by animated,
  // and we forward the setNativeProps to native button
  setNativeProps = props => {
    this.button.setNativeProps(props);
  };

  startAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.animation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1500
    }).start(() => {
      Animated.timing(this.state.animation, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 300
      }).start();
    });
  };

  render() {
    const animatedColor = this.state.animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [["white", "black"]
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* Animated works also on props (like color) not only styles */}
        <AnimatedButton
          ref={(ref) => (this.button = ref)}
          title="Press Me"
          onPress={this.startAnimation}
          color={animatedColor}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**CutomButton.js**

```
export default class CustomButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={this.props.onPress}
        style={{ ...this.props.touchableStyle }}
      >
        <View
          onPress={this.props.onPress}
          style={{ ...styles.buttonStyle, ...this.props.style }}
        >
          <Text style={{ ...styles.text, ...this.props.textStyle }}>
            {this.props.title}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle: {
    marginVertical: 5,
    paddingBottom: 3,
    borderRadius: 15,
    alignSelf: "center",
    backgroundColor: "tomato",
    elevation: 7
  },
  text: {
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have not used color property anywhere.

Comment: Hello Jaydeep, thanks for the response. I updated the question and added more info about the colors. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a hint from @Jaydeep Galani I checked the styles in the CustomButton and I did the following changes and now the title of the button animates.
Thanks Jaydeep!

```
  <Text style={[ styles.text, {color: this.props.color} ]}>
            {this.props.title}
  </Text>
```

Here are the final changes so the backgroundColor would also work.

```
export default class CustomButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={this.props.onPress}
      >
        <View
          onPress={this.props.onPress}
          style={[ styles.buttonStyle, {backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor}]  }
        >
          <Text style={[ styles.text, {color: this.props.color} ]}>
            {this.props.title}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

```
render() {
    const animatedColor = this.state.animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ["white", "black"]
    });

    const animatedBackgroundColor = this.state.animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ["tomato", "lightblue"]
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* Animated works also on props (like color) not only styles */}
        <AnimatedButton
          ref={(ref) => (this.button = ref)}
          title="Press Me"
          onPress={this.startAnimation}
          color={animatedColor}
          backgroundColor={animatedBackgroundColor}
          // textStyle={animatedColor}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```